# Understanding Difference in results between two code solutions

Tags: javascript

I am newbie here in more way than one, so please go easy on me :)

**Here is a problem I was tasked with solving using javascript:**

Print out the numbers from 1 - 20.
The rules:
For numbers divisible by 3, print out "Fizz".
For numbers divisible by 5, print out "Buzz".
For numbers divisible by both 3 and 5, print out "FizzBuzz" in the console.
Otherwise, just print out the number.

**Here was my first attempt at approaching it:**

```
 var numberArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

for(var i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++){
    if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0){
       console.log("FizzBuzz"); 
    }
    else if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 !== 0){
        console.log("Fizz");
    }
    else if(i % 3 !== 0 && i % 5 === 0){
        console.log("Buzz");
    }
    else {
        console.log(numberArray[i]);
    }
}
```

**This returned the following incorrect values:**

FizzBuzz
2
3
Fizz
5
Buzz
Fizz
8
9
Fizz
Buzz
12
Fizz
14
15
FizzBuzz
17
18
Fizz
20

**I then took a different approach which DID result in the correct answer:**

```
    var fizBuzz = function() {
        for (i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0 && i%5 === 0) {
        console.log ("FizzBuzz");
        } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log ("Fizz");
        } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log ("Buzz");
        } else {
        console.log (i);
        }
        }
};

fizBuzz();
```

Would someone be willing to help me understand what was wrong about the first approach? This is really bothering me :)

Comment: Your start with `i=0` in your first loop and with `i=1` in your second loop!

Comment: ..and thus, the first number it checked was 0 not 1

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html (No offense. The author mentions the very same problem as an interview test for programmers.)

Comment: voted as off-topic: this is a better fit for code-review. Besides: _"minimal understanding"_ is subjective, but this, IMHO, doesn't show a minimal understanding... sorry

Comment: what do you mean by minimal understanding? Also what does off-topic mean? Should this have been posted in a different category or something? I was very close on this..just needed a little nudge, which Or Neeman kindly provided below. I was using i % 3 instead of numberArray[i] % 3 and so on...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem disagree. he's not asking for a review of a specific implementation, but instead for help figuring out why one implementation worked and another did not. Specifically that goes against Code Review's on-topic statement point #5 at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, because all the code does not, in fact, work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you were checking the divisibility of i (which starts at 0) rather than of numberArray[i] (which starts at 1).

Comment: this was it! I was using i % 3 instead of numberArray[i] % 3