# Array with numbers 1-20

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm brand new to javascript.  I was working through a problem earlier where I needed an array that included the numbers 1 thru 20.

**I did this with the following:**

```
var numberArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
```

**QUESTION:**

I can't help but think that this is not efficient (and certainly not scalable).  Is there a way to create an array that automatically populates with sequential values between 1 and 20, or 1 and 1000 for instance?

Comment: Why not use a for loop instead of the array?

Comment: You can make a for loop, but then you could use just a for loop... what do you want to do?

Comment: Yes, but the result doesn't sound useful.

Comment: If you need this for your [FizzBuzz program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337013/understanding-difference-in-results-between-two-code-solutions), the answer is that the entire array there is unnecessary (you can set the range in an integer and print the result using `i+1`).

Comment: I am no longer using an array as part of my fizzbuzz solution, but am trying to understand different approaches and how to make them more efficient. Using the array (even though this is not the best approach) I wanted to learn if I could create the array without listing it out explicity. Sounds like another for loop to solve this is the answer. I hadn't gotten to .push yet in my learning, but this is very useful!

Comment: The point is that you will never need an array that regular because you can calculate the necessary value on the fly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a simple loop to do what you want;

```
var numberArray = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
    numberArray.push(i);
}

console.log(numberArray);
```

Answer (score 14):

Here's a oneliner:

```
var myArr = Array(20).join().split(',').map(function(a){return this.i++},{i:1});
```

or a tiny bit shorter:

```
var myArr = (''+Array(20)).split(',').map(function(){return this[0]++;}, [1]);
```

Both methods create an empty `Array` with 20 empty elements (i.e. elements with value `undefined`). On a thus created `Array` the `map` method can't be applied <sup>**1**</sup>, so the `join` (or string addition) and `split` trick transforms it to an `Array` that knows it. Now the `map` callback (see the MDN link) does nothing more than sending an increment of the initial value (`{i:1}` or `[1]`) back for each element of the `Array`, and after that, `myArr` contains 20 numeric values from 1 to 20.

Addendum: ES20xx

```
[...Array(21).keys()].slice(1);
```

`Array.map` => [**See also...**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

See also this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-sfu85y?file=index.js) project.

<sup>**1**</sup> Why not? See this [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20333745/3116322), and [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949651/1487756) for a more profound explanation

Comment: wow thats pretty even though I dont understand how it works. the other answer above I get because I've worked with the for loop. I'll have to dig into this :)

Comment: Hi @PhilPowis, I added a bit of explanation to my answer, hope it helps you along.

Comment: Very nice - about twice as efficient as the most efficient for loop solution at 10000000 iterations, at least in Chrome.

Comment: @KooiInc it's a bit confusing to say '_Array(20) doesn't know the map method_', the map method is actually there _Array(20).toString()===Array(20).map(function(a){return 'a'}).toString()_ (see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20333745/3116322)

Comment: @Ande: yep, reformulated the answer, added your link and another