# Array.map doesn't seem to work on uninitialized arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to set default values on an uninitialized array using the map function but it doesn't seem to work, any ideas on how to set default values?

Consider this code snippet I tried in Chrome console.

```
> var N = 10;
> var x = new Array(N);
> x
  [undefined x 10]

> x.map(function(i) { return 0;});
  [undefined x 10]
```

I was expecting the array to be initialized to 0's.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you'd like to fill an array, you can use `Array(5).fill()` and the methods will then work as expected--see the alternate related answer from aasha7. Older pre-fill approaches include:

```
Array.apply(null, new Array(5)).map(function() { return 0; });
// [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

After some reading one of the [posts linked in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947892/creating-range-in-javascript-strange-syntax/18949651#18949651), I found this can also be written as

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 5}).map(function() { return 0; });
```

---

However, trying to use `.map` on undefined values will not work.

```
x = new Array(10);
x.map(function() { console.log("hello"); });

// so sad, no "hello"
// [ , , , , , , , , ,  ]
```

`.map` will skip over undefined values :(

Comment: +1; the problem here is that `map` skips *indexes* that have never been assigned a value. Compare `Object.keys(new Array(2))` (no enumerable properties) to `Object.keys([undefined, undefined])` (two enumerable properties, `0` and `1`). In the first case, the array has no values assigned to any indexes; in the second case, the indexes `0` and `1` have been assigned the value `undefined`.

Comment: @apsillers, you are correct. To clarify, `var x = new Array(5);` just has `x.length == 5` and the `Array.prototype`. Aside from that, no enumerable keys are set.

Comment: very cool trick - I'm still trying to understand what is the difference between "new Array(5)" vs "Array.apply(null, new Array(5))"

Comment: @Raja you should totally check out [Ziraks explanation on this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18949651/1487756)

Comment: I ran into this problem and it actually _does_ work on `undefined`  values, (undefined as in the javascript type), just not on uninitialized values.

Comment: map does not skip over undefined values, see: `[undefined].map(() => {console.log('ayo')}`. It's because Array(5) creates an array with 5 **empty** slots, not 5 undefined values. See answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66449263/javascript-spread-with-array/66449468#66449468

Answer (score 14):

I'd just like to point out that you can now do:

```
Array(2).fill().map(_ => 4);
```

This will return `[4, 4]`.

Comment: `new` and `null` are not required, this works the same `Array(10).fill().map(_ => 0)`.  +1 anyway

Comment: or even shorter `Array(10).fill(0)`

Comment: ```[...Array(2)].map(_=>4);```

Answer (score 3):

That's how it's described by the ECMAScript Language specification

Here's the relevant part of `Array.prototype.map`, as described by ([§15.4.4.19](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19))

- ...
- *8*.  Repeat, while `k < len`

  - *a)* Let `Pk` be `ToString(k)`.
  - *b)* Let `kPresent` be the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of `O` with argument `Pk`.
  - *c)* If `kPresent` is `true`, then

    - *do the magic*
- ...

Since there is no initilized member in your array, calling e.g `new Array (1337).hasOwnProperty (42)`evaluates to `false`, hence the condition in step 8.c is not met.

You can however use a little "hack" to do what you want.

`Array.apply(null, { length: 5 }).map(Number.call, Number) //[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

How this works has been thouroughly [explained by @Zirak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949651/1487756)

Answer (score 2):

Also possible solution without `Array.prototype.fill`:

```
[...Array(10)].map((_, idx) => idx); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.map()` function skips entries that have never been assigned values.  Thus on a newly-constructed array like yours, it does essentially nothing.

[Here is the MDN description.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

With `.map()`, undefined elements are skipped and not passed to the callback so if you have an array with no elements that actually contain anything, then the callback is never called.

From the [ECMA script 262, 5.1 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), section 15.4.4.19:

> callbackfn is called only for elements of the array which actually
>   exist; it is not called for missing elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can populate an array with zeros [using this function](http://www.2ality.com/2013/11/initializing-arrays.html):

```
function fillArrayWithNumber(n) {
  var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(n));
  return arr.map(function (x, i) { return 0; });
}

fillArrayWithNumber(5); // [0,0,0,0,0]
```

Or with a small change you can use indexes instead:

```
function fillArrayWithIndex(n) {
  var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(n));
  return arr.map(function (x, i) { return i; });
}

fillArrayWithIndex(5); // [0,1,2,3,4]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZ92d/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Building on a previous answer there is new shorter syntax. The OP wanted to create an array of N items initialized with 0.

```
var N = 10;
var x = new Array(N).fill(0);
// x is now: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

You also don't need the `new` - it's optional in this context.

Check the [compatibility of your target platform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) and/or use a pollyfill if not available.