# Why does .map treat Array(x) differently from [...Array(x)]?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The question is, what is the difference between `Array(5)` and `[...Array(5)]` See below variable `c` and `d` is the same yet `.map` treats it differently.

```
let a = [...Array(5)].map((k,i)=>{
  console.log("Hello");
  return i;
})
console.log(a);

let b = Array(5).map((k,i)=>{
  console.log("Hello");
  return i;
})
console.log(b);

let c = Array(5)
let d = [...Array(5)]
console.log(c) // c and d seem to be the same
console.log(d)
```

Comment: explain what you mean by using map on `Array(5)`

Comment: `Array(5)` returns an array with an initial capacity of 5 elements, all of which are empty. `[...Array(5)]` returns an array with 5 undefined elements. `map` skips over empty elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array.map doesn't seem to work on uninitialized arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333654/array-map-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-uninitialized-arrays)

Comment: The accepted answer in your linked question is actually not true, map doe snot skip over `undefined`, this snippet works just fine: `[undefined].map(() => {console.log('ayo')})`. It specifically does not run in this case because it's empty slots, which is different from `undefined`. See my answer below. @HereticMonkey

Comment: this seems like a complete valid question, idk why it got closed, im voting for reopen

Comment: @gpt I don't know why you tagged me in your comment. My comment says that `map` skips over **empty** elements. There are also *seven other answers* on the question which answer this question. There is no need for yet another answer to the same question.

Comment: @Vitim.us It's a valid question, but it's a duplicate. Why reopen only to close it again?

Comment: I tagged you because the accepted answer in your linked question says "`.map` will skip over undefined values :(", misleading answer.

Comment: @HereticMonkey if its a duplicate it should be marked as such, not closed as invalid question.

Comment: @gpt But there are several other answers on that question, and *you can edit the answer* if you find it misleading.

Comment: @Vitim.us It's not closed as an "invalid question"; there is no such close reason. It's closed as lacking details and clarity. As the first comment asks, what is meant by using map on `Array(5)`. If the OP simply edited their question to answer that clarification, it would not be closed.

Comment: I disagree that the question is unclear, maybe the title is vague. But it is very obvious he is questioning why both constructs doesn't behave the same even tho a lot of people would expect them to behave the same.

Comment: Hopefully this question was clarified. I'm assuming this is easy for full time javascript developers. @Vitim.us

Answer (score 1):

Because when you directly call `Array(5)`, it creates an empty array, not an array with 5 `undefined`. This is why nothing happens when you call map because there is nothing for it to iterate over, so it immediately returns.

> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and 232-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with its length property set to that number (Note: this implies an array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values). If the argument is any other number, a RangeError exception is thrown.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array